# Average price with categories SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table called Book which has the following fields

```
BOOK
BOOK_CODE
TITLE
TYPE
```

There are many options within TYPE, eg SFI,FIC,MYS

I need a query that shows the average price for each option

currently have this but its just showing the average price of all the books:

```
SELECT AVG(PRICE) FROM BOOK
WHERE TYPE IN ('SFI','MYS','ART','FIC');
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hint : **`GROUP BY`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You can use `GROUP BY` to group values from a column, and, if you wish, perform calculations on that column ... " More info: [**MySQL - GROUP BY Clause**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm)

```
SELECT
    Type
    ,AVG(Price)
FROM Book
GROUP BY Type
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a **[`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)**

**Query**

```
select `type`, avg(`price`) as `avg_price`
from `book`
where `type` in ('SFI','MYS','ART','FIC')
group by `type`;
```